# How to enable paste on HTML page with locked "Cmd+V"?

Tags: javascript, passwords, browser, clipboard, credit-card

Often you can enter pages, which has disabled paste from Clipboard,
like input password or Credit card numbers, which is very silly,
because who keeps in memory complex passwords or CC numbers?
People like to use password keepers for those things.
I found that problem is in:

```js
... b.bind("paste",function(){return!1} ...
```

How to deal with it?
How to unbind interception of paste method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with script - you need to open browser console and execute:

```js
$('*').each(function(){                                                
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.unbind('paste');
});
```

Need to inject jQuery first, if there is no one