# Script to enable "paste" on Website

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, clipboard, copy-paste

The problem concerns the particular site: [tickets order on NS.nl](https://www.ns.nl/producten/s/railrunner). On that page there is text input field to enter the email, and that field has Ctrl-V (paste) disabled.

Question: What Greasemonkey script will enable paste on the field?

I have looked into various solutions, namely:

- [Pasting password disabled at certain websites](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/916528?fpa=1)

  - [Source of "yes paste" script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/40760)
- [How to enable paste on HTML page with locked “Cmd+V”?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28267088/267197)

and came to the following script which (unfortunately) does not work for the given site (testing with FF v40, Greasemonkey v3.4):

```
// Taken from http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/40760
unsafeWindow.disable_paste = function() { return true; };

// jQuery is already available on the page:
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Site generates the form on-the-fly, so we schedule the necessary modifications for later:
setTimeout(function() {
    $j(document).off('copy paste', '[data-regex=email], [data-regex=emailRepeat]');
    $j(document).off('keyup keydown keypress cut copy paste');

    // Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266689/how-to-enable-paste-on-html-page-with-locked-cmdv
    $j('*').each(function(){                                                
        $j(this).unbind('paste');
    });
}, 2000);
```

Delayed execution (via `setTimeout()`) is used because the site builds the form dynamically. The "problematic" element is shown on the following screenshot:

[image: Form field element that has disabled paste]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- To unbind the events you should provide the original handler set by the page:

  ```
  // ==UserScript==
  // @name         Re-enable copy/paste of emails
  // @include      https://www.ns.nl/producten/s/railrunner*
  // @grant        none
  // ==/UserScript==

  $(function() {
      $(document).off("copy paste",
                      "[data-regex=email], [data-regex=emailRepeat]", 
                      $._data(document, "events").paste[0].handler);
  });
  ```
- Another method that turned out to work only in Chrome is to assign a direct event listener for `oncopy`/`onpaste` element properties, thus it'll have a higher priority than the site's listeners attached to the `document`. In your listener prevent other listeners from seeing the event via [stopImmediatePropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation):

  ```
  var input = document.querySelector("[data-regex=email], [data-regex=emailRepeat]");
  input.onpaste = input.oncopy = function(event) { event.stopImmediatePropagation() };
  ```

Comment: Great! I think I saw this solution somewhere, but certainly messed up things. I have noticed that the script works only when called from `setTimeout()` as I provided above (meaning that it I take it literally as you provide, it does not work, at least in FF). I tried to use `$(document).on('copy paste', '[data-regex=email], [data-regex=emailRepeat]', function(event) { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); });` but that does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: See the updated answer. Note that instead of using a timer it's sufficient to wrap the code in `$(function() { ....... });` so that it'll be executed once both the document and jQuery are loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, wrapping into `$(function() { })` does not work for me. It worked for you? Actually, I don't see why it should, as `$(document).on('events', 'selector', function)` is also triggered once given node is attached to DOM (so I would say it's better candidate to work fine).

Comment: Yes, it works for me on FF42+Greasemonkey3.5 and Chrome+Tampermonkey. Have you tried the exact userscript I posted or have you modified something?

Answer (score 28):

The selected answer did not work for me. I found this simple script did work though:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return true;
}, true);
```

Which was found here: https://www.howtogeek.com/251807/how-to-enable-pasting-text-on-sites-that-block-it/

Edit: May need to stop propagation for `keydown` as well for some websites.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return true;
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code can be used to enable Copy & Paste on websites which is disabled.
Just paste the below code into the Browser console.

```
javascript:(function(){
  allowCopyAndPaste = function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return true;
  };
  document.addEventListener('copy', allowCopyAndPaste, true);
  document.addEventListener('paste', allowCopyAndPaste, true);
  document.addEventListener('onpaste', allowCopyAndPaste, true);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work just fine. 
However how this answer differs from the one [posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68414487/267197)?